# Scraping reviews from a few pages

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to make a for loop to go to a few product pages and scrape their reviews. The code is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(webpages)) {
  title <- product %>% html_elements(".title") %>% html_text()
  reviews <- product %>% html_elements(".raterv-rowttl+ p") %>% html_text()
}
```

The web pages:

```
'https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3867/Apple_Cider_Date_Vinegar_Gummies.html',
'https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3068/Opti_Bright_Lutein_20.html', 
'https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3302/Phytoberry_Antioxidant_Drink_Triple_Pack.html'
```

I'm trying to append the title and reviews into a dataframe but cant as some product pages have more reviews which will cause it not be able to append to the table. May I know whether is there a way to put all reviews into a list for each product/ make it into a JSON?

Comment: Would you share the URL address(es) of the web page(s)? It might help. If there is more reviews per page, then (I guess) `reviews` become a list. You can take the first element from the list.

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz Sapijaszko. I have changed my question

Answer (score 0):

We can simply loop using `for` and store results in a list.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

#make vector of urls
url = c('https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3867/Apple_Cider_Date_Vinegar_Gummies.html',
'https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3068/Opti_Bright_Lutein_20.html', 
'https://www.signaturemarket.co/my/marketplace/snack/3302/Phytoberry_Antioxidant_Drink_Triple_Pack.html')

#get reviews
    reviews = list()
    for(i in url){
      review = i %>% read_html() %>% html_elements(".raterv-rowttl+ p") %>% html_text()
      review = list(review)
      reviews = c(reviews, review)
    }
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "I loved this drink. Comes in convenient sachets to pop it in my bag. The taste is delicious with a tangy sour note which is great. Bought a second box already. "          
[2] "Harap dapatbkesan seeprti yg di inginkan..rasanye ajak tajam dan pekat. tapi still ok boleh minum..x pahit langsung..tapi kalau x suka rasa tajamnya boleh campur dg air.."
[3] "hope to help moisture my eye..."                                                                                                                                           
[4] "The taste is better when mixed with half cup of water, like it!"                                                                                                           

[[3]]
character(0)

#get title of reviews
    titles = list()
    for(i in url){
      title = i %>% read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes('.raterv-rowttl') %>% 
        html_text()
      title = list(title)
      titles = c(titles, title)
    }
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "Delicious with tang"    "Mata mmg rabun teruk.." "taste good"             "Good for eyes"         

[[3]]
character(0)
#get product id
prods = c()
for(i in url){
  prod = i %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('.title') %>% 
    html_text()
  prods = c(prods, prod)
}
```

To convert lists to data fame

```
titles = `names<-`(titles, prods)

dd = ldply(reviews, as.data.frame)
dd1 = ldply(titles, as.data.frame)

df = cbind(dd1, dd)

colnam = c('Product1', 'Title', 'Review')
df = `colnames<-`(df, colnam)

               Product1                  Title
1 Opti-Bright Lutein 20    Delicious with tang
2 Opti-Bright Lutein 20 Mata mmg rabun teruk..
3 Opti-Bright Lutein 20             taste good
4 Opti-Bright Lutein 20          Good for eyes
                                                                                                                                                                      Review
1           I loved this drink. Comes in convenient sachets to pop it in my bag. The taste is delicious with a tangy sour note which is great. Bought a second box already. 
2 Harap dapatbkesan seeprti yg di inginkan..rasanye ajak tajam dan pekat. tapi still ok boleh minum..x pahit langsung..tapi kalau x suka rasa tajamnya boleh campur dg air..
3                                                                                                                                            hope to help moisture my eye...
4                                                                                                            The taste is better when mixed with half cup of water, like it!
```

Comment: May I know how could I convert the list into a dataframe with column headers of               
```Title Reviews 
"Delicious with tang"    "I loved this drink. Comes in convenient sachets to pop it in my bag. The taste is delicious with a tangy sour note which is great. Bought a second box already. "```